# hudson cannot access git repository

Tags: git, ssh, hudson, gitosis

I am trying to get hudson to pull from a remote repository, I have set up an ssh trust relationship between the hudson user from /usr/lib/hudson/.ssh/id_rsa.pub to the gitosis keydir (like I have done for hundreds of other users)

when I ssh in as hudson and run

> git clone git@gitserver:project

I get

> You shall not pass!
>
> Enter Password:

is there any reason the hudson user cannot clone from gitosis but every other user can?

I have tried with a fresh install of hudson as well.

HUDSON_HOME is set to /usr/lib/hudson

have tried git path as git and /usr/bin/git

any help appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with ssh, the one environment variable which is important here is `$HOME`.
And the "`$HOME`" of the Hudson user might not be set/known from the Hudson process, even though that "Hudson user" does have a home.
See "[Creating SSH keys for Gerrit and Hudson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712443/creating-ssh-keys-for-gerrit-and-hudson/3712619#3712619)" for more details and [check your permissions on both the local and the remote sides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858928/git-ssh-setup-permission-denied-publickey).

`HUDSON_HOME` isn't relevant for ssh.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182012/problem-with-hudson-git-gitosis-on-windows for a similar symptome, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188710/hudson-git-plugin-not-working-on-windows on a similar solution.