# Hudson(Jenkins) and remote git repository get permission denied

Tags: git, ssh, hudson, jenkins, gitosis

I have setup hudson to check out from my remote git repository but i get

```
**Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,keyboard-interactive).**
```

my git repository uses gitosis and works when i clone via the command line. Hudson is running as the same user

here is a larger part of the log with hostnames and directories edited

```
Checkout:workspace / /Users/me/.hudson/jobs/HudsonJob/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@363adfb4
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository origin
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin' : Could not clone gitosis@myserver:myproject
ERROR: Cause: Error performing command: /opt/local/bin/git clone -o origin gitosis@myserver:myproject /Users/me/.hudson/jobs/HudsonJob/workspace
Command "/opt/local/bin/git clone -o origin gitosis@myserver:myproject /Users/me/.hudson/jobs/HudsonJob/workspace" returned status code 128: Cloning into /Users/me/.hudson/jobs/HudsonJob/workspace...
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,keyboard-interactive).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I also tried running the following from a command line

```
/opt/local/bin/git clone -o origin gitosis@myserver:myproject /Users/me/.hudson/jobs/HudsonJob/workspace
```

It works except but i have to specify a password for it to work.

my guess is that the hudson build fails since it has to prompt for a password.
Usually i guess that adding my public key to .ssh/authorized keys would do the job but the authorized keys for gitosis has that public key autogenerated with some extra commands.

So i am wondering how i can allow hudson access without having to type a password?

Comment: Is it a bit related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076488/hudson-cannot-access-git-repository ?

Comment: The HOME variable is set to /Users/me when looking into the hudson system properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would suggest using gitolite as gitosis is no longer actively developed.

Use keys that don't require a password.